# Getting red cross mark when trying to enable a check box in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application which consists of two buttons and a check, when either of the button is enabled the check should be enable, if not then disabled.
However when I try to enable the check box I am getting a red cross mark in my winform as shown in attachment. Below code I am using for enabling the check box.

```
form1.checkBox1.Enabled = form1.button1.Enabled || form1.button2.Enabled
```

[Form Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKcJh.png)

Here the area of red cross mark is where the check box control is there. I am new to winform, so is this the correct way for changing UI element?

I have given a localized view of the form as well as the functionality, as these three controls are isolated from other controls and functionality of Form.

Comment: a red cross means that the gui is crashed, check for errors and debug your code.

Comment: Yes It is Enabled only in code........While asking question it went wrong. I will edit the question

Comment: Is there any multithreading involved?

Comment: I am not using multi threading.

Comment: @Lyze If GUI is crashing will I get an exception for this crash and would it crash when I run this application on any server. Because currently in one of the machine this issue is coming, in rest all machines no red cross mark is coming.

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/11/22/winforms-and-the-big-red-x-of-doom/) is an explanation of this. Without seeing all related (to this checkbox) code it's kind of hard to say more.